# Multi-threading WCF with Singleton Pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, singleton

I have build WCF application and now I would like to run this service as multi-threaded. 
I am running three threads in parallel and each thread has WCF service object. at the start of each thread I am executing login function to check user is valid or not & once valid then rest of the methods are gets executed using service object.
My question is, How can I create singleton pattern to create WCF Service object, which will do login are return me service object and same object then shared with multiple threads.
I looked into some articles but they have singleton with lock statement. But lock blocks other thread to use instance.
I need to share service instance with all threads & when all thread release the service object, I have to call logout method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use a TCP listener as the service.  Each client would use a different port number.  There are two way of implementing.  The server can list at one port number and then when client connects move client to a different port.  Or have server open multiple port numbers and then have clients try different port numbers until a connection is established.  See examples on following webpage.  Examples use socket class but you can use an class that inherits the socket such as TcpListener and TcpClient : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Singleton and multi-threading are almost mutual exclusive terms. Why do you want to share "service object"? Why don't create object per thread?

Comment: @jdweng: how TCP listener is related to WCF? WCF could use any transport?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I cannot create new object per thread because login has third party api validation for user, and this returns active session object. so i want to create only one object which will shared by all threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class clsSingleton
{
    private static clsSingleton instance = null;        

    clsSingleton()
    {

    }

    public static clsSingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new clsSingleton();
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Name";
    }


}
```

//How to call method GetName

```
string Name= clsSingleton .Instance.GetName();
```